# How do I model a PC being swallowed by a dragon in D&D4e?

Tags: dnd-4e, dragons

I recently read of an attempted dragon-slaying strategy, which involved a magic-user getting swallowed and then summoning Tenser's Floating Disc.

Besides all of the other problems with this setup, I'm wondering, how would the swallowing be modeled? How long can a PC survive inside the stomach of a dragon, under D&D4e rules?

Comment: Please link the Tenser's Floating Disc strategy.  I'd be very interested in finding out how that could possibly be used to slay a dragon.

Comment: I presume you mean other than dead? This scenario ignores the chewing process

Comment: @Iszi Shrink your player in some way. Summon tenser's disk at an opportune moment, say as you're going past the throat area of the dragon. Hope dragons only have scales on the outside. Hope your friends get to you before you get fully digested

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Swallowing** has been modeled in D&D 4e on other creatures.  You should be able to adapt one of them to the dragon just fine.  For example, the Purple Worm <sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/monster.aspx?id=377)</sup>

> Swallow (standard, at-will)
>
> The purple worm tries to swallow a bloodied Medium or smaller creature it is grabbing; +21 vs Fortitude; the target is swallowed.
>
> - The swallowed target is inside the purple worm and is `dazed` and `restrained` until it is no longer swallowed.
> - The swallowed target has line of sight and line of effect only to the purple worm
> - No creature has line of sight or line of effect to the swallowed target.
> - The only attacks the swallowed target can make are basic attacks.
> - At the start of each of the purple worm’s turns, the swallowed target takes 10 damage plus 10 acid damage.
> - When the purple worm dies, the target is no longer swallowed and can escape as a move action, appearing in the purple worm’s former space.

*(I reformatted the quote a bit to make it more readable)*

Answer (score 1):

You could assign a fire|cold|poison|etc-based ongoing damage based on the dragon's type, plus a fixed starting damage due to munching, plus, perhaps, some rolls to endurance to simulate the difficulty of performing a summoning while being digested.